# JavaScript can't read text-box values

Tags: javascript, html

When I run this code, I get this error in the console

> cannot read property 'value' of null

As you can see the `txt1` and `txt2` values are not null and the javascript is linked to the HTML code, I have tested it with an audio file.

```js
var audio = new Audio('sound/saw.mp3');
var min=0;
min=document.getElementById('txt1').value;
var max=0;
max=document.getElementById('txt2').value;
```

```html
<label id="lbl1" for="txt1">lowest number </label>
<input id="txt1" type="text" class="enjoy" value="0">

<label id="lbl2" for="txt2">highest number </label>
<input id="txt2" type="text"  class="enjoy" value="100" />
```

Comment: are those controls already loaded in DOM?

Comment: you have the javascript code above or below  the input ?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a timing issue. Javascript can't find nodes until they've been loaded into the dom. Just wrap your JS in a `window.onload()` function:

```
window.onload = function(){
   var audio = new Audio('sound/saw.mp3');
   var min=0;
   min=document.getElementById('txt1').value;
   var max=0;
   max=document.getElementById('txt2').value;
}
```

That will ensure that the nodes exists before you try to access them. You can read a little more about that here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing / in the tag:

Should be:

If you want the content of a tag you have to use:

document.getElementById("txt1").innerHTML

if you want an attribute value you have to use

document.getElementById("txt1").getAttribute("value")

If you want to access the value of a text field use:

document.getElementById("txt1").value

Anyway use JQuery to navigate the DOM, it's much easier than the DOM API.